# Paramiko Channel Closing after exec_command(); scripts abort immedietely after

Tags: python-2.7, ssh, paramiko

I want to ssh into a host and execute shell commands there. So far, I have a class that I instantiate (that uses paramiko) to handle all ssh connections and to execute commands in that connection:

```
import paramiko
class ShellHandler:

def __init__(self, top, host, user, psw):
    self.ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    self.ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    self.host = host
    self.user = user
    self.psw = psw
    self.top = top

## Connect to remote host
def connect(self):
    try:

        self.ssh.load_system_host_keys(filename=None)
        self.ssh.connect(self.host, username=self.user,
                         password=self.psw, port=22)

        channel = self.ssh.invoke_shell()
        # self.stdin = channel.makefile('wb')
        self.stdout = channel.makefile('r')

        print "Correct Username %s and Password %s\n" % (self.user, self.psw)

    except paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException as e:
        print "Incorrect Username %s and Password %s " % (self.user, self.pwd)
        return 2

    except socket.error as e:
        if e.errno == errno.ECONNREFUSED:
            print "Connection Error\n"
        else:
            print "Something went wrong\n"
            self.top.insert(INSERT, "Something went wrong\n")
        return 1

    return self.ssh, 0

## close connection to remote host
def __del__(self):
    self.ssh.close()

## Execute command on remote host
def execute(self, cmd):
    try:
        stdin, stdout, stderr = self.ssh.exec_command(cmd)
        if(stderr):
            for errors in stderr.readlines():
                print errors.encode('ascii')
                self.top.insert(INSERT, "Something went wrong: %s\n" % (
                    errors.encode('ascii')))
    finally:
        if self.ssh is not None:
            self.__del__()

    return self.ssh, stdin, stdout, stderr
```

(NOTE: I return the ssh client because I read on another StackOverflow question that you should return the client or else the connection would close as it is now out of scope)

I have a fairly hefty script that takes ~6hrs to run. Now, when I instantiate this class with the correct username, password, and host I am able to successfully log in. After that, I am able to successfully execute the script I want. The script executes for a little bit of time, however, after that I get the following errors (from stderr stream):

```
Error: <paramiko.ChannelFile from <paramiko.Channel 1 (closed) -> <paramiko.Transport at 0x3beb8d0L (unconnected)>>>
connection closed
```

The script then aborts afterwards.

If anyone can give any tips on how to improve my code so I could better execute my scripts via ssh it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Would your script ouput lots of data? Maybe it's the ssh server killed the connection after some idle time?

Comment: The script does output lots of data into log files, but maybe some of the data takes a while to compile. If it is because of some idle time, would you know how to resolve this?

Comment: If you're using openssh, `man sshd_config` and search for `ClientAliveCountMax` and `ClientAliveInterval`. Then check `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the ssh server side. The command line `ssh` client can also set these parameters (`ServerAliveCountMax` and `ServerAliveInterval`) but I don't know if paramiko supports that.